# How can I remove repeated characters in a string with R?

Tags: string, r

I would like to implement a function with `R` that removes repeated characters in a string. For instance, say my function is named `removeRS`, so it is supposed to work this way:

```
  removeRS('Buenaaaaaaaaa Suerrrrte')
  Buena Suerte
  removeRS('Hoy estoy tristeeeeeee')
  Hoy estoy triste
```

My function is going to be used with strings written in spanish, so it is not that common (or at least correct) to find words that have more than three successive vowels. No bother about the possible sentiment behind them. Nonetheless, there are words that can have two successive consonants (especially ll and rr), but we could skip this from our function.

So, to sum up, this function should replace the letters that appear at least three times in a row with just that letter. In one of the examples above, `aaaaaaaaa` is replaced with `a`.

Could you give me any hints to carry out this task with `R`?

Comment: "This task" not currently specified clearly. Trailing repeated vowels may need to be handled differently, but this is not clear from description.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I did not think very carefully on this, but this is my quick solution using references in regular expressions:

```
gsub('([[:alpha:]])\\1+', '\\1', 'Buenaaaaaaaaa Suerrrrte')
# [1] "Buena Suerte"
```

`()` captures a letter first, `\\1` refers to that letter, `+` means to match it once or more; put all these pieces together, we can match a letter two or more times.

To include other characters besides alphanumerics, replace `[[:alpha:]]` with a regex matching whatever you wish to include.

Comment: Thanks, what about if you want to exclude some letters from this? For instance, exclude letters L and R.

Comment: `[:alpha:]` means `a-zA-Z`; if you want to be specific, you can say, e.g. `[a-zA-KM-QS-Z]` to remove upper case L and R; see `?regexp`

Comment: Here is a variation using a perl style zero width lookahead regexp: `gsub("([[:alpha:]])(?=\\1)", "", s, perl = TRUE)` . It matches all but the last in any run of alphabetic characters.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck will `[[:alpha:]]` work with `perl=True`? It's not valid PCRE syntax.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck for this specific task, your version is much slower for no real gain. Still, nice as a side note.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should pay attention to the ambiguities in your problem description. This is a first stab, but it clearly does not work with "Good Luck" in the manner you desire:

```
removeRS <- function(str) paste(rle(strsplit(str, "")[[1]])$values, collapse="")
removeRS('Buenaaaaaaaaa Suerrrrte')
#[1] "Buena Suerte"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DWin. The example with "Good Luck" does not bother me at all and I accept and apologize for the ambiguities. Things in English does not work as in spanish in this sense. I tried your solution and it works as I desire. By the way, I have edited the question in order to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to replace letters that appear AT LEAST 3 times, here is my solution:

```
gsub("([[:alpha:]])\\1{2,}", "\\1", "Buennaaaa Suerrrtee")
#[1] "Buenna Suertee"
```

As you can see the 4 "a" have been reduced to only 1 a, the 3 r have been reduced to 1 r but the 2 n and the 2 e have not been changed.
As suggested above you can replace the `[[:alpha:]]` by any combination of `[a-zA-KM-Z]` or similar, and even use the "or" operator `|` inside the squre brackets `[y|Q]` if you want your code to affect only repetitions of y and Q.

```
gsub("([a|e])\\1{2,}", "\\1", "Buennaaaa Suerrrtee")
# [1] "Buenna Suerrrtee"
# triple r are not affected and there are no triple e.
```