# How to remove multiple consecutive special characters in R?

Tags: r, regex, special-characters

How can I alter the following strings to not contain multiple consecutive question marks / other special characters in R?

```
"Nice one!!!"
```

should become

```
"Nice one!"
```

and

```
"Whazzup????!!"
```

should become

```
"Whazzup?!"
```

I experimented with multiple regex commands without success. Obviously I can replace two question marks with one but I want it to be independent of the amount of special characters.

This is different from the marked duplicate because it deals with special characters.

Comment: the above solution does not work for special characters? I just learned I need to use [[:punct:]] instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub("([[:punct:]])\\1+", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "Nice one!" "Whazzup?!"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Nice one!!!", "Whazzup????!!")
```

Comment: I guess it was because JonGrub posted the same solution a little bit earlier. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Yes, indeed. I upvoted your post because I guess you typed at the same time. Also notice how this was wrongfully marked as a duplicate -_-

Comment: sorry corrected it :)

Comment: @akrun I'm a bit baffled yours is shown to be older. When I posted mine there was nothing else here. Maybe I din't refresh but I took my answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164667/how-can-i-remove-repeated-characters-in-a-string-with-r) and looked up regex for punctuation. No more copy and paste involved than usual...

Answer (score 5):

A simple and straightforward solution would be to use gsub for the punctuation regex:

```
x <- "Whazzup????!!"
gsub('([[:punct:]])\\1+', '\\1', x)
[1] "Whazzup?!"
```