# GNU R: How to remove repeated characters at the beginning and end of every word of a string?

Tags: r, string, replace, character

In GNU R, I need to remove repeated characters at the beginning and end of every word of a string.

In case I have the input

```
str <- "Tthis iss a splendiddd ddayyy"
```

The output should be

```
"This is a splendid day"
```

Does someone know how to do this? Thank you very much in advance !

With best wishes,
Eric

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use gsub(). Find more information here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164667/how-can-i-remove-repeated-characters-in-a-string-with-r

Comment: I'm thinking using the right `pattern` in `gsub()` should solve the problem (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=353072 might be of help)

Comment: You can use gsub(). Find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164667/how-can-i-remove-repeated-characters-in-a-string-with-r

Comment: Are you concerned about removing duplicates when they should be there?  For example: llama, ooze, all, small, pill, dill, ball, too, pass, grass, etc...

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your inputs! I need to do this for text in French. In this language actual words starting or ending with double letters are extremely uncommon. I can only think of "zoo". Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The first `gsub` removes duplicate leading characters and the second the trailing.  The first regular expression matches a word boundary followed by any character followed by that same character possibly repeated.   It then replaces the match with the character matched by the capture group, i.e. the part within parentheses.  The upper or lower case is ignored.  The second works similarly for trailing duplicates.

```
ss <- gsub("\\b(.)\\1+", "\\1", str, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
gsub("(.)\\1+\\b", "\\1", ss)
## [1] "This is a splendid day"
```