# Removing duplicate elements of a string

Tags: r, string

I have a string: `string <- "YYYYYXXXYYXZYYZ"` and I want to retain only a single copy of the repeated elements, so that string would read the following: `"YXYXZYZ"`. What is the best way to do this R?

Comment: Glad it works. My answer and explanation are almost exactly the same as Yihui's in the linked question, so I'll delete it.

Comment: Cool, thanks Frank, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This with gsub:

```
gsub('([[:alpha:]])\\1+', '\\1', string)
```

From another answer fom @Yihui Xie at [How can I remove repeated characters in a string with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164667/how-can-i-remove-repeated-characters-in-a-string-with-r)

Comment: That's an excellent link but we need to mark this as a dupe in light of that