# Remove characters which repeat more than twice in a string

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I have this text:

```
F <- "hhhappy birthhhhhhdayyy"
```

and I want to remove the repeat characters, I tried this code

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11165145/10718214

and it works, but I need to remove repeat characters if it repeats more than 2, and if it repeated 2 times keep it.

so the output that I expect is

```
"happy birthday"
```

any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `sub`, with the pattern `(.)\\1{2,}`:

```
F <- ("hhhappy birthhhhhhdayyy")
gsub("(.)\\1{2,}", "\\1", F)

[1] "happy birthday"
```

Explanation of regex:

```
(.)          match and capture any single character
\\1{2,}      then match the same character two or more times
```

We replace with just the single matching character.  The quantity `\\1` represents the first capture group in `sub`.

Comment: just `gsub("(.)\\1{2,}", "\\1", F)` or `gsub("(.)\\1\\1+", "\\1", F)` is enough ;-)

Comment: @Cath Taking what the OP literally said, we want to replace only letters which occur in a series of _three_ or more.  Your suggestion would do the replacement on _two_ or more.