# Remove repeated semi-colons in R?

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I've used `tidyr::unite` to merge many columns using a semi-colon as the separator. I changed all NA's to blank spaces (''). When I run the `unite` command I get what I want but also many cells with repeated semi-colons - left over from the blank cells. Here is an example of my string.

```
string <- c('community centre;;sports hall;;;','community centre;;;;;')
```

After finding this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164667/how-can-i-remove-repeated-characters-in-a-string-with-r) on a similar topic I came up with this regular expression. But it's cutting the tailing characters off my string.

```
gsub('([[:alpha:]])\\;+', '\\;', string)

[1] "community centr;sports hal;"
[2] "community centr;"
```

After going back forth I'm unable to get any further. I'd like a regex that gives me this output.

```
[1] "community centre; sports hall"
[2] "community centre"
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, only `;` after a letter should be matched, right? Try `gsub("^;+|;+$|(;)+", "\\1", string)` if it is not necessary.

Comment: Looks like it is what you need. Sometimes, processing a million records with two regexps might be costly, so I [posted the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675674/3832970) adding the `stringr` code, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a two-step process for simplicity. First replace multiple `;` with `"; "`, then remove `"; "` from the end of the string. Fancier regex will be more efficient but less straightforward.

```
string = gsub(";+", "; ", string)
string = gsub("; $", "", string)
string
# [1] "community centre; sports hall" "community centre"
```

Comment: thanks for this. It works well. Just wondering, I tried it with `stringr::str_replace` and couldn't get it to work. Does this approach work with the stringr package?\

Comment: `str_replace` only replaces the first match. You'd want to use `str_replace_all` for the first line to get all the matches.  `str_replace` should be fine for the second line. (And I could change the second line to `sub` instead of `gsub`. `sub` is like `str_repalce`, `gsub` is like `str_replace_all`)

Answer (score 0):

We could use:

```
stringr::str_remove_all(string,";(?=\\W+)|;$")
[1] "community centre;sports hall" "community centre"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a single regex for the job:

```
gsub("^;+|;+$|(;)+", "\\1", string)
```

Or, if you prefer `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(string, "^;+|;+$|(;)+", "\\1")
```

It matches

- `^;+` - one or more (`+`) `;` chars at the start of the string (`^`)
- `|` - or
- `;+$` - one or more (`+`) `;` chars at the end of the string (`$`)
- `|` - or
- `(;)+` - Capturing group #1 (repeated one or more times) capturing a single `;` one or more times.

The replacement is just the contents of Group 1 that is an empty string if the first two alternatives match, and `;` if the third alternative matches.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZWj3G/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%3B%2B%7C%3B%2B%24%7C(%3B)%2B):

[image]