# Removing consecutive duplicate symbols from a vector

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a vector which is full of `+` symbols separating valid characters. I need to remove replicate, consecutive `+` symbols, but retain non-consecutive `+` symbols which are used as separators.

Below is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c(A="a+++a+b+c++++d+d+d"))

                name
  a+++a+b+c++++d+d+d
```

Below is the desired output:

```
           name
  a+a+b+c+d+d+d
```

Below is the code I tried to use to substitute the repeated `++` symbols with `+`.

```
sub("++", "+", df$name)
```

When I try this I get the error below:

```
Error in sub("++", "+", df$name) : 
  invalid regular expression '++', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'
In addition: Warning message:
In sub("++", "+", df$name) :
  TRE pattern compilation error 'Invalid use of repetition operators'
```

Comment: Not explicitly about `+`, but maybe it can get you going: [How can I remove repeated characters in a string with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164667/how-can-i-remove-repeated-characters-in-a-string-with-r); "To include other characters besides alphanumerics, replace `[[:alpha:]]` with a regex matching whatever you wish to include."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(name=gsub("\\++","\\+",name))
```

output:

```
           name
A a+a+b+c+d+d+d
```

Comment: Hi @MaxMiak. Thanks a lot for this! It did the trick. In addition the following code was added to ensure that the leading and trailing `+` symbols are removed: `df <- df %>% mutate(name=gsub("\\++","\\+",name)) %>% mutate(name=gsub('^\\+|\\+$', '',name))`

Comment: Most welcome, in case that worked for you, you can ✅ to accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

`sapply` should work

```
df$name <- sapply(df,  function(x) { gsub("\\++", "\\+", x) })
```

Comment: note that "\\++" doesnt mean exactly two plus sign. ist more than 1.